# Join 2 columns into 1 result in android

Tags: android, sql-server

I'm working with a piece of code and i am trying to display to column values in my one Text view.
Here is my code

```
                        String query = "select * from mo_test where username= '" + Search.toString()+"'  ";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        z = "Search successful";
                        name1 = rs.getString("fName" + "lName");
                        isSuccess=true;
                        con.close();
```

The error i get when i run the application is

> Invalid column name fNameLname

All i want to do is show the users first name and last name in one Text view

Comment: Are you really using SQL Server on an Android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
rs.getString("fName" + "lName");
```

with

```
rs.getString("fName") + " " + rs.getString("lName");
```

`getString()` needs a single column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the database by using an expression

```
select (fname + ' ' + lname) as name from mo_test . . .
```

Note:  This only returns the column being referenced.

SQL Server uses `+` for string concatenation.  Other databases usually use `||`.

You should also learn to use parameters, instead of munging query strings with parameters values.